# Request python funciona en v2.6.6 pero no en 3.10.1

Tags: python, python-requests

Mi consulta es la siguiente estoy armando un request para que una API me devuelva el token de autenticacion. Lo estaba haciendo en python 3.10.1 (es la version que tengo en mi PC) y no funcionaba, pero luego, al adaptar el codigo a la versión 2.6.6 (los servidores donde va a correr el script tienen esa version vieja) para mi sorpresa el código funciono. El tema es que no se muy bien por que. Este es el codigo en 3.10:

```
def GetToken(user,secret):
        _headers={
            'accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
        payload={
            "grant_type":"client_credentials",
            "client_id":user,
            "client_secret":secret,
            "scope":"scope1"
        }
        
        payload_url=urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
        resp=requests.post(end_point,headers=_headers,data=payload_url)
        if resp.status_code in range(200,299):
            print("OK")
        else:
            print(resp.status_code)
        
    
 GetToken(client_id,secret)
```

El cual me arroja el siguiente error:

**Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL]
dh key too small (_ssl.c:997)')))**

el codigo en v2.6.6 es el siguiente:

```
def GetToken(user,secret):
    _headers={
        'accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    payload={
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "client_id":user,
        "client_secret":secret,
        "scope":"scope1"
    }
    payload_url= urllib.urlencode(payload)
    con = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url)
    con.request("POST","<mi_end_point>",payload_url, _headers)
    resp=con.getresponse()
    if resp.status==200:
        data=resp.read()
        api_res = ast.literal_eval(data.decode("utf-8"))
        token=api_res.get("access_token")
        return token
```

El cual funciona correctamente. Honestamente no puedo ver cual es el error que estoy cometiendo en la version 3.10